# How to fix 'Data Not Specified' error in GoogleChart -> "Material Design Dual Y Charts"

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization, linechart

The array I input as "Data" is not recognized by the Chart component. Checked many times the array structure and I can't find any error/mistake/difference in it.

I tried modifying its structure but it didn't work. This is my DataArray:

```
0: [{type: "date", label: "Día"}, 
"Peso","DROGA1","DROGA2","DROGA3","DRUG4","DRUG1"]

1: [Tue Dec 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: [Wed Dec 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: [Thu Dec 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4: [Fri Dec 21 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5: [Sat Dec 22 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6: [Sun Dec 23 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7: [Mon Dec 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
8: [Tue Dec 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
.
.
.
22: [Tue Jan 08 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 18, 0, 1050, 0, 0, 105]
23: [Wed Jan 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 18, 0, 1050, 0, 0, 105]
24: [Thu Jan 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 18, 0, 1050, 0, 0, 105]
25: [Fri Jan 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 18, 0, 1050, 0, 0, 105]
26: [Sat Jan 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100, 18, 0, 1050, 0, 0, 105]
```

It should show the different readings for each day.

Comment: Edited google's fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6gLf4oqh/2/ No error about data (left materialOptions the same) OG code and example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart?hl=ru#dual-y-charts

Comment: will you please share the code that loads the data?